# Unable to Start this Storm Project

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

As a Storm learner, I am unable to start the project on my local machine the link of the project is - https://github.com/CGCL-codes/Nereus. I had directly started with the command storm jar /home/join/Nereus/target/Nereus-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar soj.biclique.KafkaTopology -n 40 -ks 1 -pr 100 -ps 100 -f1 4 -f2 4  -infile sorted_20161101  -wr 40000 -ws 40000 -tr 46000 -ts 46000 --s band -t 2 -nps 3 -ns 600 -mig -jump -conti -e1 50 -e2 50

Unable to start the project on local machine this project is showing again and again this problem
[image]

Comment: 1. This is not an Apache Storm question. Try to ask Nereus project authors at Github.
Briefly looked at the code:
2. -1 code = "Wrong parsing cmd line arguments". Try to select arguments with which the topology starts stably and then gradually replace it with your own.
3.  I didn't see the --remote or -ltr flag in your cmd line.
By default, topologies start in remote mode, which needs a configured cluster. Let's try to add option "-ltr 3600". All Nereus storm topologies run locally have a 5-second default time.